# IOS Ad Hoc distribution link does nothing

Tags: ad-hoc-distribution, ios6.1

Trying to create a distribution for testing. When the link is clicked in safari on the ios device nothing happens (literally. No errors). We are using an enterprise cert and a universal distribution profile. The mime types are correct and everything worked great until we moved to a new folder on the web server. Please help. If there's a way to see what the error is in safari that would be a good start.

Here's the relevant code.

### html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
test
</title>
</head> 
<body>
<center>
<h1>Test</h1>
<a href=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://uri/app.plist>Install</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

### plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://uri/app.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>appId</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>apptitle</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### edit

wiping the iPad in question seems to work, but this isn't really a viable solution if it happens to a personal device. Any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this issue and rebuild and archiving with Xcode 4.6.2 (released April 15) has resolved it for me.

Comment: Have upgraded and trying to find a case to test this on. Still curious why certain devices decided to suddenly not work and there's a fix in the new Xcode.

Comment: It could be a different issue, I was having failures installing on all my devices until I update Xcode

Comment: I believe it is. Thanks for your answer all the same. Now , at least, we're up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on iOS8. The install button would automatically disable in Safari.  The cause was that my plist file was invalid.  That seems odd at first but apparently Safari checks the link out before you even click it.  I grabbed a copy of the plist file from a previous build and (after updating the app version number) it worked.  It's also worth noting that Xcode 6 doesn't generate plist files like the older versions did. For more info on Xcode 6/plist you can check out this link as well:

[Xcode 6 Save for Enterprise Deployment does not create plist for ipa anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910387/xcode-6-save-for-enterprise-deployment-does-not-create-plist-for-ipa-anymore)

Comment: also worth noting that newer version of iOS require the link in the plist to be HTTPS.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1