# Xcode 6 Save for Enterprise Deployment does not create plist for ipa anymore?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, enterprise

Xcode 5 helped in creating plist descriptor for enterprise ipa.
Xcode 6 (6A313) creates ipa only. 
Is this a bug or intentional change? If so - what would be the reason for taking a step back?

If I did not have previously generated plist using Xcode 5, I would need to crete it manually myself.
Do you know of any automatic tool which would help in the process?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. Needed to put a build out last night. I ended up just reusing an old plist and updating it. Here's a template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>[INSERT URL HERE]</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>[INSERT BUNDLE ID HERE]</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>[INSERT VERSION HERE]</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>[INSERT APP TITLE HERE]</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (the one above is less verbose but it was put in 6 days afterwards)

Comment: Hi All,



It seems like Apple has removed this feature to generate the .plist needed for enterprise distribution from the archive process for developers that don't have an enterprise account. What you should be able to do is modify one of the .plist files generated by the last version of Xcode and use that to point to the URL where you will host your new .ipa file. Don't know why Apple would have removed this feature from the archive process, but it could have something to do with their push to better accommodate the enterprise market

Comment: Thanks @AbdulYasin -  Event i am using enterprise profile but getting same.So looks like apple removes plist functionality. But there might be a some other way.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Enterprise Distribution. How does this Plist thing works?

Comment: Can someone explain more about what to insert to [INSERT URL HERE] ?
I've never done this before, so I don't have an old project to look up to. I've just built a .ipa file by command line and not sure what to do next to accomplish the purpose of this old tutorial: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air
P/S: I don't have an Enterprise account

Comment: And what if i don't have XCode 5 and dependent on classes that are only available in XCode 6?

Comment: Even though this works, it still doesn't explain WHY Apple broke (disabled?) the functionality of generating the corresponding plist.

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't find other solution than reusing an old **`.plist`**-file --- worked perfectly.

Comment: And if I don't have an old plist file? /n00b (trying to create my own with pir800's c&p)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue in following manner(As @pir800 mentioned)-

**1) Take plist file of an old project and rename it name should be same as ipa file.**

**2) Changed  values of following keys in plist file - a) url.   b) bundle-identifier.  c) title.**

And then put ipa and plist on server. Remaining things are same like Xcode5.

But it is very bad, apple should inform to developer and mention such type changes in document.

I do not my way is correct or wrong but my Enterprise In-house Distribution build properly downloaded and working. ....:)

I replied same on apple developer also. You can check this thread **https://devforums.apple.com/message/1076995#1076995** also
If any one find better solution then please reply.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

To extend the accepted answer, you need to be a team member of the 299$ enterprise account. Go to Project Navigator (ProjectName) -> Targets -> General tab and select the account that is assoicated with 299$ enterprise developer account. If you cannot find the account you are looking for, go to XCode -> Preferences -> accounts and check if you are the admin / agent / team member of the said account and then proceed to make the ipa and plist file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about enterprise deployment, but in XCode 7.0, you can create a manifest.plist while exporting an archive for Ad Hoc deployment...

1. Select Product > Archive
2. When the build finishes, select the archive you wish to export and choose "Export..."
3. Choose "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment"
4. Select your dev team
5. Choose the desired option for "Device Support"
6. **On the "Summary" page, check the box beside "Include manifest for over-the-air installation."  This will add a manifest.plist to the folder where the .ipa file was saved.** - Click "Next"
7. Insert the correct paths to the .ipa, display image, and full size image and click "Export"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm experiencing exactly the same thing, having to re-use a plist file generated from Xcode5. Just one other thing to add: The validate button, that we're presented with after archiving, does not validate my App correctly. It gets past "Preparing Archive" but then throws up an error, "No matching provisioning profiles found for Applications/plumbsApp.app" - None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application identifier, beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups.

Now, dismissing this and continuing with the "Export", creates my .ipa file and my users are able to install correctly, with the correct url, of course. So, not totally sure why this is happening. I had the beta release of Xcode running but used the final release of Xcode6. Perhaps the beta, comment, in red-herring. Has anyone else experienced this, where the validation of the archive fails in this way but the App installs ok?

Comment: Doesnt answer question and attempts to ask new question.

Comment: Bit harsh. Only trying to help!

Comment: Im not trying to put you off. The reason I down voted was your answer does not address OP's question and is anecdotal content more appropriate to a comment, and then you ask a question. As a general rule ask yourself "Does this thing I'm writing answer the OP's question" & "Does this thing I'm writing provide a better answer  than an existing one". SO answers are not a conversation about a general topic.