# Xcode 6 archive for AdHoc distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I have to distribute an app via AdHoc distribution. With Xcode 5 after the archiving, I select the option "Save for enterprise distribution" and then insert the web url where I upload the `.ipa` and the `.plist`.

Now in Xcode 6 this option is disappeared and I can't able to generate `.ipa` and `.plist`, but only the `.ipa`.

There is someone that know how to create `.ipa` and `.plist` in Xcode 6 for upload this files on a web site to allow an easy way for tester to install the app on iOS7 where testglight doesn't run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 Save for Enterprise Deployment does not create plist for ipa anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910387/xcode-6-save-for-enterprise-deployment-does-not-create-plist-for-ipa-anymore)

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1):

Download Xcode 5.1.1. and install it separately from Xcode 6.1. (in a different folder).
This way you can generate .plist files easily since you mentioned that you need it for iOS 7.
You can always keep Xcode 5.1.1. around and open your current project from it.

Solution 2):

Use your old .plist files or create a new one :
[Xcode 6 Save for Enterprise Deployment does not create plist for ipa anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910387/xcode-6-save-for-enterprise-deployment-does-not-create-plist-for-ipa-anymore)

Solution 3):

Wait for apple to fix this "bug" in the upcoming Xcode versions :).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plist from previous exports, you can use the same one. I distribute an app using enterprise deployments and all I do is create the ipa and upload it to the server. I created my plist file quite some time ago. You can also update the data in there if you need to, but so far I have not run into any issues with pushing a new version with out updating that file.

Answer (score 0):

When you press export you get 3 options one of them is save for enterprise deployment.
But you can use [testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com) instead and save the app for adhoc deployment.

Comment: Yes, this is ok. But testflight only run on iOS 8. So how is possible whit Xcode 6 install on iOS 7 devices ?

Comment: I know, read the question ;)
The question is simple: how to generate ipa and plist from Xcode 6 for install on iOS 7 (where test flight is not available)

Comment: As Justin said below, take an old plist and modify it with the values you want.

Comment: Fry, you can use TestFlight for iOS 7 via their web page: http://testflightapp.com - but perhaps they are not accepting new users?

Comment: @Reid They are accepting. You are right its possible to install TEstFlight by web page.